# How to do something inside component after triggering a redux action?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

i want to domething inside component after an action is done.
for example i want to show a modal to user after a request is successfully done, or disable some elements if request is done successfully.

should i use callbacks? or promise? if yes, then how

```
export const fetchHorizontalSpecialProductsList=(virtinId)=> {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: Types.REQUEST_FETCH,
        });
        HomeApi().specialProducts({vitrinId:virtinId,rows:8,page:0,frontTypeList:["SPECIAL"]}).then((response) => {
            dispatch({
                type: Types.REQUEST_SUCCESS,
                payload: response,
            });
//
.then(probably here)
//
        }).catch((response) => {
            dispatch({
                type: Types.REQUEST_FETCH_FAIL,
                payload: response,
            });
        });
    };
};
```

when the request is successful i need to show a modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to connect to Redux store, for example, in Redux state you should declare these properties:
success: false/true.

Then with the action received is REQUEST_FETCH_FAIL or REQUEST_SUCCESS you just need to use the switch..case statement in reducer to change the variable to true/false.

Your container connected to Redux store, depending on the props success true/false, you can doSomething() you would like to do,

Comment: yeees, thank you. even though i use this method everyday i don't know why i thought there would be another way

Comment: how should i know state is updated, i mean i need something like a broadcast receiver. or probably in componentWillUpdate or DidUpdate?

Comment: Usually, I use it in componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps), we can know if (nextProps.success), then we can doSomething().

Comment: Just read from the redux state by connecting your component by `connect` of `react-redux`.